# Retrieve Arraylist in success function of AJAX without JSON

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to send AJAX request to a servlet and in response I want to fetch an Array list sent by the servlet. I tried using several examples given in several websites, talking about JSON.
None of them worked. In eclipse, it says GSON or JSON(whatever) class not found. I have no problem with build path. I have added the required jar.But, it doesn't work. So I thought to pass arraylist as response without JSON.

The code is:jsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#admin_edit_listbox").click(function(){
        var useridval=$("#admin_edit_listbox option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({                
            type:"get",
            url:"EditUserBetaAjaxServlet",
            data:{userid:useridval},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data){

                var arr=new Array();

                arr=data;               
                $("#f_name").val(arr[0]);
                $("#l_name").val(arr[1]);
                $("#t_name").val(arr[2]);
                $("#role").val(arr[3]);
                $("#email").val(arr[4]);
                $("#phone").val(arr[5]);                    
            }               
        });
        }); 
});
</script>
```

The servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String fname="example";
    String lname="test";
    String team="like this";
    String role="ok";
    String email="possible";
    String phone=null;
    ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
            arr.add(0, fname);
    arr.add(1, lname);
    arr.add(2, team);
    arr.add(3, role);
    arr.add(4, email);
    arr.add(5, phone);
    out.print(arr);
    System.out.println(arr);

}
```

The list that is received is used to fill text boxes in jsp. The whole list is coming to jsp,but the text boxes do not get data as per the items. It is not parsing the elements as expected. Please help.

Comment: Ad GSON not found: it is not about eclipse build path but web application dependencies. Required jars need to be placed under WEB-INF/lib directory within your war file (or exploded folder).

Comment: @Leos Literak I have done that.But, tell me how to do, without json?

Comment: I miss setting content type on your response. I doubt that out.print(arr) will generate anything meaningful. Print each element separately line by line.

Comment: out.print(arr) successfully passes the list to AJAX success function.I checked it using alert  method in success function. It is showing all elements as expected. But, when I retrieve using arr[0],arr[1], etc ,it prints like [ A etc because the list returned was for example [Amitabh]. I want to get "Amitabh" at arr[0].help me.

Comment: Using ArrayList.toString() (implicitelly called) will generate [] around list items. Why do you not iterate? E.g. for (String s : arr) {
out.println(s); }

Comment: i am not getting it.You are telling me to iterate at server side? I don't know if this will work,but please look at my jsp page.I want to fill data to the text boxes.Please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: The problem got solved using JSON. But, without JSON it could not be.